Need help in calculating $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{x_{(2)}-x_{(1)}}\int_{x_{(1)}}^{x_{(2)}} f(t) \ dt)$, where $x_{(i)}$ are related Beta distribution
Suppose $Y, Z \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$.
Let $a = g(\min(y,z)),\ b=g(\max(y,z)).$
How can I calculate the expectation $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t) \ dt\right]$$ where $f(t) = g^{-1}(t)$?
A straightforward calculation involves finding the integral inside and using the joint density of $a,b$ from transforming the joint density of $y,z$. That direct calculation looks complicated even for a simple function $f$ such as a monomial.
The original expectation can also be written as $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(f(X))]$, where $X\sim \text{Uniform}(a.b)$. However, this observation alone doesn't seem to simplify the calculation.
Are there any simple ways to calculate the above expectation, or are there any formulas/theorems/special properties that might help?

You don't know anything about $g$ ?

If $f$ is four times differentiable and $g$ is twice differentiable, you could derive an approximation based on sequential second-order Taylor approximations.
